# My crafters are addicted to Death's Breath! How can I help fulfill that need?

Tags: diablo-iii

That Mystic is such an addict.  All I want is to tweak my items, and she refuses to do so much as get up unless I wave one of these under her nose.  It's gotten so bad, she sometimes wants two or even *three* of them!  She's lazy, too.  She'll only provide a couple tweaks, neither of which are useful, therefore necessitating yet *more* Death's Breaths.  She's so bad, even Shen and Haedrig have gotten addicted, too!  Which means I have to give them some, too, or they refuse to do *their* jobs, either.  I tell you, some people...

What's a great way to stockpile this rare (and apparently, highly addictive) resource?  Do higher difficulty levels offer a better chance of it dropping?

Comment: Acknowledging you have a problem is the first step.  Unfortunately, the artisans can't seem to see they have a problem.

Comment: Patch 2.0.4 (released 3 days after this question, lol) has made it so that Death's Breath is no longer needed for lvl 61-70 crafted rares and the requirement of Flawless Royal gems on lvl 70 crafted sets has been changed to Marquise gems.  Seems there was an intervention!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, higher difficulties will drop Death's Breath at a higher rate. So if you need loads of them, it is best to farm Rifts on Torment 1 and higher.

The drop chances are as follows:

- Normal - 15%
- Hard - 18%
- Expert - 21%
- Master - 25%
- Torment 1 - 31%
- Torment 2 - 37%
- Torment 3 - 44%
- Torment 4 - 53%
- Torment 5 - 64%
- Torment 6 - 77%

[Source](http://eu.battle.net/d3/de/forum/topic/10119772941?page=2#21)

Comment: Why are Rifts better than Bounties?  If the drop rate is the same, then there doesn't seem to be a difference.

Comment: @Frank Because the drop rate for Legendaries is better in Rifts and in general, the end boss provides often 1 or 2 Death's Breath as a drop. There is no guarantee for that, but completing the rift also yields some Death's Breath. BUt, as you said, in the end it does not really matter. What matters is difficulty.

Comment: @frank some rifts are also full of elites you literally move from elite group to elite group the entire level

Comment: @Assylum Rifts are better than bounties because they have higher monster density (which means more chances to roll death's breath. Also, there is a set (SAGE'S?) at level 70 that gives you double death's breath whenever they drop from having full set.